# How to save and restore text in TextView

Tags: android

I have multiline TextView on my Fragment. This TextView must to show data from Thread.

```
private void method1(){
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int index = 0;
                    while (index < 100){

                        updateLog(Integer.toString(index));
                        index ++;

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();
}

    private void updateLog(String log){
        currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                syncLogTextView.append(log+" \n");
            }
        });
    }
```

It's works, but if I want to switch to another fragment, I will lose all data in TextView. After return I will  have empty TextView. I need to save and restore data in TextView and synchronize with my thread. How  I can implement correctly it?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate log - thread (data) part from view
You can create a storage (private String mystore) and update it with thread
and take data from property (storage) as soon as you want to show it